# File Menu on Android Studio disappears after my PC upgrade from windows 8.1 to windows 10

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012

My Android Studio works well on Windows 8.1, but after I upgrade my PC from Wind 8.1 to Wind 10. The "File" menu disappears from Menu bar. That makes me unable to create a new project. Although the existing project is still able to run.

I try use shortcut, ctrl-F, but it does not work.

Any one can tell me how to resolve this problem, or I must re-install Android Studio.

Thanks

Sunny

Comment: FWIW, this might be an issue with IntelliJ IDEA, the IDE on which Android Studio is based.

Answer (score 0):

After trying something, I find a way to resolve this problem:
Go to Setting => Menus and Toolbars => Main menu. At this situation,  File menu is not on the list. Highlight the Main menu, than click the "Restore Default" button on the bottom right. Now the File menu appear on the list,  as well as on the  Android studio menu bar.